# Show that $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Given $z = f(\frac{(x+y)}{(x-y)})$ for $f$ a $C^1$ function, I need to show
$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$.
I tried setting $u=\frac{x+y}{x-y}$ but eneded up with $xf'(u)\frac{(x-y)-(x+y)}{(x-y)^2} + yf'(u)\frac{(x-y)+(x+y)}{(x-y)^2}$ which doesn't seem to simplify to 0, at least the way I did it. Am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: You have done it correctly, it simplifies to 0.

Comment: Do I need to know the value of f'(u)? If so how do I find that

Comment: No, you don't need the value $f'(u)$. Notice $xf'(u)((x-y)-(x+y))+yf'(u)((x-y)+(x+y))=xf'(u)(-2y)+yf'(u)(2x)=f'(u)(-2xy+2xy)=0$